# How to dynamically generate wordpress editor on frontend?

Tags: tinymce, editor, wp-editor, wysiwyg

I want to initialize the wordpress editor dynamically on frontend. I have tried to include the following scripts:

```
wp_enqueue_script('editor');
wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
```

Then to init the editor like this:

```
tinymce.init({
  mode : 'specific_textareas',
  editor_selector :'tinymce'
});
```

But it does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

You are in luck. There is a Wordpress internal function for that. It's the [wp_editor](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor) function.

The function does all the work for you. It enqueues the right scripts and style-sheets. Just pass the configuration you want.

```
wp_editor('Enter your text here', 'editor_id_here')
```

Comment: I think she asked if there is a way to add editors dynamically from javascript from from PHP.